# Div is under other divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put  a form on a div where I have an image:[Form  on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L5Q9.jpg)

The problem is that I cannot float the form to the right side and also the form is under the other divs just as the image I've also attached here:
[Form under other divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI6VI.jpg)

```css
.slider__size {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 570px;
 position: relative;
 font-family: "DINNextLTProLight";
}
.slider__img__position {
 justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
}

.slider__consolidado__img__position {
 justify-content:center;
    align-items:right;
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
}



.img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
 }

.title__box {
 padding-top:200px;
 position: absolute;
 padding-left: 50px;
}


.h1__home span{
  color: white; 
   font-size: 50px;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     font-weight: bolder;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 992px) { 
 .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
  max-width: 150%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
 }

}
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 600px) {
 .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
  max-width: 250%;
 } 
}
@media (max-width: 400px) { 
 .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
  max-width: 300%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
 }
@media (max-width: 300px) { 
 
 .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
  max-width: 400%;
 }
}
 

}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-fixed-bottom { display: none;}
 
}

@media (min-width:768px){
 .form__consolidado__color {
  margin-top: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0px black;
 }
 
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 slider__size">
      <div class="slider__consolidado__img__position"> 
        <img class="img-responsive img__blend__filter" src="/slider_notebook.jpeg" 
             alt="Crédito Família">
      </div>
      <div class="title__box">
        <h1 class="h1__home"><span>Comece<br>a realizar<br>sonhos</span</h1>
        <button class="btn-default btn-padding btn__slider__color_orange">
          Saiba mais
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form__consolidado__color">
      <h2 class="form__title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <h3 class="form__subtitle">What's Lorem Ipsum</h3>
      <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" name="contato" action="" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group row">..... </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 div__info__color">
            <h2 class="text__blue__h2">.....</h2>
            <p class="text__grey__14">......</p>
          </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the form being under other divs can be solved by setting the "z-index" property of the div containing the form to a high value which will make the form appear on the first level

```
z-index: 100

.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.form__consolidado__color {
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked!! I couldnt float to the right side though. Do you know how I can do it? `float:right;` didn't work, neither margin-left;

Comment: could you give me a link to your deployed project so i can inspect and fix that issue cause i couldn't find the bug from your description

Comment: I wish Amr, but I was not able to set the server then I decided to finish the front end first because it was taking me so much time without any progress. If you have any idea how I can set my webpage as others can see the link it would be great. Thank you very much

Comment: There is too many characteres and I'm not able to share the entire code here. Do you know any other way I can send you? Maybe by email..

Comment: amr.alaa.ismail@gmail.com

Comment: After reviewing your code

     .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.form__consolidado__color {
         float: right;
      }

Comment: Thank you very much. It didn't work so I used `margin-left: 45%` Might be not the best way but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the float problem with `margin-left:45%;`